# How much amount of data can be sent by http POST and GET methods in java servlet?

Tags: http, servlets

I want to know how much amount of data (like kb or mb) we can send through the GET method and POST method. can anyone tell ?

Comment: Infinite. Is it good enough of an answer for you? When you download a file from the net you are doing a GET in essence.

Comment: Are you asking how much the client can submit to the server in the request, or how large the server's response can be?

Answer (score 2):

The GET method has size limitation: only 1024 characters can be used in a request string.
and there is no limit of post method .